# NoForeignKeysError between x and y

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
Base = declarative_base()


class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://...')
        self.session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        print(engine.connect().execute(
              'Select * From Customer LEFT JOIN CustomerContact On Customer.ID = CustomerContact.CustomerID')
              .fetchall())


class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Customer'
    ID = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    Name = Column(String)
    contacts = relationship('CustomerContact')


class CustomerContact(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'CustomerContact'
    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    CustomerID = (String, ForeignKey('Customer.ID'))
    Name = Column(String)
    Title = Column(String, default='')
    ContactInfo = Column(String, default='')
    Notes = Column(String, default='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = Database()
    s = db.session
    s.query(Customer)
```

Running these two lines:

```
session.query(Customer).all()  
session.query(Customer).join(CustomerContact).all()
```

results in

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships 
 between 'Customer' and 'CustomerContact'.
```

Also it seems that querying anything related to those two classes spits out those errors

I've already checked for typos and other threads as well as running a raw sql statement to see if there's an issue elsewhere but it worked perfectly fine

I was following the example at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many
and can't for the life of me figure out what is exactly wrong

If someone can help point me in the right direction to troubleshoot this further or where the issue is, that would be amazing.

Comment: You've made a simple typo: `CustomerID = (String, ForeignKey('Customer.ID'))` assigns a 2-tuple as `CustomerID`. You meant to create a `Column`.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I can't believe I missed that! Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to call Column() on

```
CustomerID = (String, ForeignKey('Customer.ID'))
```

Thank you Ilja Everilä!

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the **foreign key** in the select itself.

Instead of:

```
session.query(Customer).join(CustomerContact).all()
```

Try:

```
session.query(Customer).join(CustomerContact, CustomerContact.CustomerID==Customer.contacts).all()
```

Comment: SQLAlchemy should be able to use the existing foreign key relationship automatically, so something else is wrong here.

Comment: Also, `CustomerContact.CustomerID==Customer.contacts` produces a rather funky ON clause: `ON "CustomerContact"."CustomerID" = ("Customer"."ID" = "CustomerContact"."CustomerID")`, probably due to how `Customer.contacts` is adapted.